# How can you control the logic of an iPhone pre-generated settings (bundle) pane

Tags: iphone, settings, logic, plist, bundle

How can I control the logic of say 5 "automatically generated" on/off switches using a method similar to this http://knol.google.com/k/iphone-sdk-application-preferences?pli=1# when the app isn't running.  Some of my settings are contingent on other settings being on or off.  IE setting logical gates for this plist's pre-generated settings view.  I have this working in my App but I can't have my app having invalid settings because of 5 on/off switches that are independent of each other because the app can't currently control them, when I need some of them linked.  So basically I just disable this pane, and the user can only change settings in the app.  It would be nice to using the "General" Settings app...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to validate the current App Settings on startup and notify the user if you discover problems with the settings.